# Beam DataFlow ReadFromPubSub id_label for GCS Notification

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

Currently, I'm doing a streaming process with DataFlow for moving uploaded blobs from GCS into BigQuery. However, I found that there were several pub/sub messages pointing to the same objectId which causing duplication at the BigQuery end.

I'm aware that the GCS notification is guaranteed ***at least once delivery***, hence it would be possible that I will have duplicate pub/sub message(s) for a given blob file.

I read the Python Beam documentation that it can utilize *id_label* as a unique record identifier. To deduplicate based on the blob filename, I tried to insert attributes.objectId on id_label args. Nevertheless, it seems it doesn't work (I still receive duplicate message):

```
| "Read from pub/sub topic" >> ReadFromPubSub( topic=config["prod"]["input_pubsub"], with_attributes=True, id_label="attributes.objectId")
```

Note: I'm using Beam Python SDK 2.38.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the deduplication on Dataflow side is best-effort.

> Dataflow deduplicates messages published to Pub/Sub within 10 minutes of each other.

See https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/streaming-with-cloud-pubsub#efficient_deduplication.